# How to shim HttpWebRequest Headers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to Shim the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken.token.access_token);
request.Accept = "application/json";
```

But running the Unit Test throws an exception in this part: `request.Headers.Add()` because `request.Headers` is `null`. This, in spite of initializing `Headers` in my test:

```
ShimHttpWebRequest request = new ShimHttpWebRequest();
ShimWebRequest.CreateString = (urio) => {
   request.Instance.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection {
        {"Authorization", "Bearer abcd1234"}
   };
   //also tried initilizing it like this:
   //WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
   //headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer abcd1234";
   //request.Instance.Headers = headers;
   return request.Instance;
};
```

But `request.Instance.Headers` is still `null`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a getter for `Headers` so that it would return a `WebHeaderCollection` instead of `null`.

```
ShimHttpWebRequest request = new ShimHttpWebRequest();
ShimWebRequest.CreateString = (urio) => request.Instance;
request.HeadersGet = () => {
   WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
   headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer abcd1234");
   return headers;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by instantiating Header property of `ShimHttpWebRequest` as follows,

```
var httpWebRequest = new ShimHttpWebRequest() { HeadersGet = () => new WebHeaderCollection() };
ShimWebRequest.CreateString = (arg1) => httpWebRequest.Instance;
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my code, you can try it:

```
public static string HttpPostWebRequest(string requestUrl, int timeout, string requestXML, bool isPost, string encoding, out string msg)
    {

        msg = string.Empty;
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetBytes(requestXML);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Referer = requestUrl;
            request.Method = isPost ? "POST" : "GET";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Timeout = timeout * 1000;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding));
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                responseStream.Close();
                request.Abort();
                response.Close();
                return result.Trim();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
        }

        return result;

    }
```